# How to get the dictionary to start displaying the values ​in parentheses?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have a question, what should I do to get the dictionary to start displaying the values ​​in parentheses?

```cs
public Dictionary<Average, ClassB> dic = new Dictionary<Average, ClassB>();
```

I have added the values ​​that I would like to assign to the key:

```cs
 dic.Add(Average.1, new ClassB(list2[i].Field));
 dic.Add(Average.2, new ClassB(Field2));
 dic.Add(Average.3, new ClassB(Field3));
```

But when I try to display them with a loop, foreach pops out of class.ClassB instead of the value.

```cs
foreach(KeyValuePair<Average , ClassB> item in dic)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key + "   " + item.Value);
}
```

Comment: You should override `ToString()` method in `ClassB`

Comment: you need to specify the property of classB you want to display, like item.Value.myProperty

Comment: "class.ClassB instead of the value" what value do you expect to be written there? and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to override `ToString`. Check the following example

```
class ClassB {
    ...

    public override string ToString(){
        return $"Prop1 is {this.Prop1} and Prop2 is {this.Prop2}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C# is trying to implicitly convert Average and ClassB into strings, if it doesn't have one it will use the type name. To solve this you can [override the ToString method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netcore-3.1#overriding-the-objecttostring-method) for ClassB

```cs
public class ClassB {
    //<class logic omitted>
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return //<put your string logic here>
    }

    //<class logic omitted>
}
```

You may want to use template strings, which allow you to easily build a string without adding them together

e.g. `$"a: {variableA} b: {variableB}"`

You can learn more about that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)